# How to print only the texts using Beautifulsoup in Python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to print only the texts from here.

Here my HTML.Purser Code

```
import requests                                                  
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup                                    
                                                             
page = requests.get('https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/abet')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')                    
synonyms2 = soup.find_all(class_='short')                            
print(synonyms2[0])                                              
print(synonyms2[0].find(class_='short').get_text())
```

Output

```
<p class="short">To <i>abet</i> is to help someone do something, usually something wrong. If 
you were the lookout while your older sister swiped cookies from the cookie jar, you 
<i>abetted</i> her mischief.</p>

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/hudacse6/WebScrape/webscrape.py", line 8, in <module>
print(synonyms2[0].find(class_='short').get_text())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

In my output i,m successfully print the class values associate with html tags but when i try to call only the texts using this line

```
print(synonyms2[0].find(class_='short').get_text())
```

it will me this error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/hudacse6/WebScrape/webscrape.py", line 8, in <module>
 print(synonyms2[0].find(class_='short').get_text())
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'.
```

How to avoid this error and only print the texts.

Comment: synonyms2 is already what you are getting from ```find_all(class_='short')```. Would ```synonyms2[0].get_text()``` work instead?

Comment: sorry i can,t understand what do u meant by that. Please don,t mind.

Comment: thank it works, thank u so much@c4llmeco4ch.

Comment: I provided you an answer. This is what @c4llmeco4ch also meant. If you are satisfied with the answer, kindly accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting the error because `synonyms2[0].find(class_='short')` returns `None`.

Use this instead:

**Code**

```py
import requests                                                  
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup                                    

page = requests.get('https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/abet')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')                    
synonyms2 = soup.find_all(class_='short')                                                                        
print(synonyms2[0].get_text())
```

**Output**

```
To abet is to help someone do something, usually something wrong. If you were the lookout while your older sister swiped cookies from the cookie jar, you abetted her mischief.
```